# Create an coloured corners for UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

For my UITableView i make images that are rounded. That is how i made it:

```
   cell.imageView.image = image;
   cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 33;
   cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 82, 0, 0);
```

Pretty easy. What i want to, is create a coloured corners for that image. Please take a loot at attachments:

[image]
[image]

On the left side, is picture of how images look now. On the right side, image with corners i wish to add. How could i do this?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you you draw a circle behind the image?

Comment: Well, thats an option :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shot in the dark but you could try setting

```
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;

cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Just change `[UIColor redColor]` to `[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]` :)